# An exeption to the general https redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have two domains that point to the same hosting. The main domain points to the root

I have an .htaccess in the root of the server that redirects from http to https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In that same hosting a second domain points to a folder in the root. Let's say  I call that folder second-domain. That domain do not have https. So in second-domain folder I put a .htaccess with that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

How can I point a domain that has no ssl, in a hosting that has a general redirection from http to https? What I did works, but I still do not know if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Try clearing  your browser  cache.

Comment: @atarkeen. So stupid of me! Sorry, now it works

Comment: I reformulate the question: is this the right way to solve that problem?

Comment: You don't need to use the rule for your second domain. If your domain doesn't have ssl then you will get an invalid certificate warning from ssl module and you can't redirect `https` to `http` without an ssl cert.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. For my second domain I do not need a ssl and I do not want to pay for it. And at the same time, I do not want to pay for another hosting either for that second domain. I suppose the question is can I have a ssl domain and a non ssl domain in the same hosting? if so, how?